# Why doesn't this boto3 python script type check?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I'm using the `boto3-stubs` package to type check my boto3 calls. Specifically, I'm using [`batch_get_secret_value`](https://youtype.github.io/boto3_stubs_docs/mypy_boto3_secretsmanager/client/#batch_get_secret_value) like so:

```py
        secrets: list['mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.type_defs.SecretValueEntryTypeDef'] = \
            client.batch_get_secret_value(
                SecretIdList=raw_config['secrets']
            )['SecretValues']
```

This appears to me to be correct code. `batch_get_secret_value` is a real method of the client and `SecretValueEntryTypeDef` is a real type in the stubs package.

However, when I type check with mypy, I get the following two errors:

```
$ python -m mypy --strict .
main.py:15: error: Name "mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.type_defs.SecretValueEntryTypeDef" is not defined  [name-defined]
main.py:16: error: "SecretsManagerClient" has no attribute "batch_get_secret_value"; maybe "get_secret_value"?
  [attr-defined]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

`boto3-stubs` is up to date on my machine. I've tried searching but I've found not a lot of people use the stubs.

In summary: why am I getting these type checking errors?

(full code for completeness:)

```py
import boto3
import json
import sys
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.client
    import mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.type_defs

def main() -> None:
    client: 'mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.client.SecretsManagerClient' \
        = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        raw_config: dict[str, typing.Any] = json.load(file)
        secrets: list['mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.type_defs.SecretValueEntryTypeDef'] = \
            client.batch_get_secret_value(
                SecretIdList=raw_config['secrets']
            )['SecretValues']
        
    return

main()
```